# jQuery needs 2 clicks to get the end result?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I'm using the isotope jQuery plugin, which seems to be acting like a bad joke.

What should be happening is what you see when you click on an `articlePost` div container within the isotope container (under 3 top posts). The animation and CSS changes take place, then you have to click a second time for the proper `left: 0px;` value to take the proper space.

The first click animates the CSS size change only. A second click moves it into the proper position.

Live example: theciv.com/vancouver

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
        var $container = $('#articlePost');
    $(window).load(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
              $('#articlePost').imagesLoaded( function() {
                $('#articlePost').isotope({
                    itemSelector: '.boxy',
                  masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 3 }
                });
        $(".read a").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var post_id = $(this).attr("rel");
            $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
            $(this).closest(".boxy")
            .animate({
            left: "0%",
            width: "100%",
            height: "300px",
            }, 500);
            $(this, "#foldOut").animate({
            height: "300px",
            }, 1000)
            .load("<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/ajax-fold/",{id: post_id});
            $container.isotope('reLayout', 'reloadItems');
        });
              });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post the code.  Double clicking requirement is usually some result of scoping improperly.

Comment: fixed the link. my geo-redirect isn't working! haha

Comment: Please don't link to live code. As soon as you fix the problem, this question becomes useless.